# How to see ping pong in web socket in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, websocket, uiwebview

I am doing websocket between webview in iOS and Socketserver.

But I am unable to watch ping-pong that happens because javascript does not have any call back methods for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/download/)**

It has a tab called **WebSocket** that shows all web socket related conversations including frames such as **Ping**,**Pong** and **Close**.

[image]