# Is there any way to sniff network traffic on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, sockets

I have to say sorry before, my english's not good.

Our app needs to fetch data form an external device through wifi.
everything's fine till I found out the vendor-supplied SDK got us damaged data.
now I need to analyze the behavior of this device to know how to communicate with it.

---

By using wireshark, there are few things I know for sure:

To connect to the device, I need 3 sockets,

### udp client*1 , tcp client*1 , tcp server*1.

First 2 client sides are not problems to us, they both use fixed port.
But the server side is now stopping me from moving forward.

After I setup two clients and connect to the device, it'll attempt to connect to the IP from these clients.

The problem is, it'll use a random port and changes every time. so I don't know which one I should bind on.
[Wireshark Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RujKe.png)
[Wireshark Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRAL8.png)

Then I came up with an idea, what if I can capture information(port number) while the device is trying to connect, and bind the port immediately.

As far as I know, even if the first connection failed, it will retry at least 5 times, I'll just wait for the next time.

Since I have no idea which port will be used, the only thing I can do is to sniff on the IP address(device).

---

here's another thing I don't understand.
Before the device try to connect to clients' IP, it send dataA first.

e.g.

### dataA : 00 01 00 00 00 **48 2e 66 d0** 00 00 00 00

### port  : 29015

and **48 2e 66 d0** changes every time, so does the port number.

maybe they're related somehow, I don't know...

### Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which language are you using, C or Objective C?  What interface are you using for handling connections?  POSIX system interfaces (`socket()`, `bind()`, `accept()`, ...) or something else?

Comment: Wireshark tells you the port numbers for all TCP and UDP connections…

Comment: Also, are you asking how to programmatically analyze network traffic, or are you asking how to predict what the client will do (for instance, which source port it will use)?

Comment: If it's your app, you know what port it's on, correct?  If you know that, you can find out the IP address and port of all clients that have connected to it.  Also, I would recommend you have a debug option in your app so that this information can be written to a log file (or audit file)

Comment: Hi @John Bollinger! I'm using Objective-c, and building an iOS app. and I only need to know which port the device is using, so I can bind the port and wait for next connection from the device (it'll retry after connect failed)

Comment: Hi @Dietrich Epp! YES! but the port number changes every time. and it random.

Comment: Hi @KevinDTimm! I got all these wireshark data because I'm using vendor-supplied SDK. It can successfully establish a connection, but the data I need are all damaged after processed by the the SDK

Comment: @gabrielchn, generally speaking, you cannot predict the source port a client will connect *from*.  Rather, the server establishes one or more fixed ports that clients can connect *to*.  The server-side port numbers are characteristic of the application -- for instance, by default, HTTP servers run on port 80.  Once the server accepts a connection (TCP) or datagram (UDP) at such a port, the application can determine from it the source port used by the client.

Comment: Yes, the source port will typically be random.  Just look at the destination port.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I got it. but what I'm trying to do is like what wireshark does(to know all the information even if the connection failed). once I know which port the device was attempted to connect, then I bind the port dynamically, because the device will retry anyway. Like a browser usually connection to "a.b.c.d:80",only the '80' changes every time, I need the port of destination but the source port. am I right?

Comment: @DietrichEpp, yes, that's what I need to capture, but I don't know how, It seems need some low level skills.

Comment: @gabrielchn, it does not make sense for the device in question to behave the way you claim it does.  It presents the same kind of problem to any conceivable server that it is presenting to you.  The only way I can imagine it working at all is if the client and server expect to be on a private network with no other devices.

Comment: So you're saying that both the source and destination port look random?  Interesting.  Maybe it's using mDNS or something like that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the wifi signal come from the device its self.  I'm sorry i didn't make myself clear. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RujKe.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRAL8.png these two images show situations from two different times when the device trying to connect to a server(app). and thank you for your patience.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, yes, it confused me to get to know how to do the right thing. I also googled 'mDNS', I think it is different, since the device decide which port it will using by its own. so I think maybe the bytes data in section 2 in my question is the device try to tell me something about the port, but I don't know how to decode it. maybe you're wonder why I didn't contact with the vendor, um... the relationship between my company and them is not so well.    and thanks a lots.

Comment: Even if the device is a wifi access point / router, it has no reason to suppose that it can successfully interact with *anything* but dedicated hardware via a truly random port.  I'm not disputing that its behavior *appears* random, but either there's some method to what it's doing, or perhaps it's simply malfunctioning.  Maybe you should take another look at that SDK -- even if it seems to be garbling the data, you may gain some insight on how to communicate with the device by monitoring how the SDK routines do it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the SDK simply use [xxx_connect: password:], the rest is in a .a file. The behavior of the device decide to connect to a server is after I setup another socket(sockA, fixed port) and send a specific string and password string to it, then the device send stringA back to sockA, after sockA receive stringA, the device start connect to a server with random port. maybe stringA is the key to the port. but to decode it is so hard for me. Thanks.

Comment: @gabrielchn - Speaking of sniffing the iOS network traffic.You can try charles proxy its has user friendly GUI to monitor the traffic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914968/how-to-see-ping-pong-in-web-socket-in-ios/39916796#39916796