# Swift 3 - Turn off badge, alert, sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, notifications, alert

I've read a lot of answers here and I can't find answers of this questions
How to stop badge, alert and sound from notifications when the application is not running ?
How to stop badge, alert and sound from notifications when the application is in Background?

in this function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

I've put completionHandler([]) without [.badge, .alert, .sound] and I still receive notifications in background when the app is runned.

Also I have function in my code that sends notification when somebody is typing to you and you see that he is typing to you when you are in-app, but when the application is not runned you are receiving notification with badge alert sound? How to prevent that?

PHP Code:

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'content-available' => 0,
    'typingNewMessage' => 'true',
    'senderId' => $your_id
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things first: Are you using websocket/socket.io for the chat in your app? And as for notifications, have you set up remote notifications in background modes?

**Background modes.**

Read up on the [docs for push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html), it sounds like you're adding steps here, or missing some. Basically as kathayatnk mentioned, his method should give you what you want. So if you haven't activated remote background notifications:

> To configure your app to process silent notifications in the
>   background
>
> 1. In the Project Navigator, select your project.
> 2. In the editor, select your iOS app target.
> 3. Select the Capabilities tab.
> 4. Enable the Background Modes capability.
> 5. Enable the Remote notifications background mode.

If this is done, you should receieve them in the background..

Also, you are using the wrong method for recieving background notifications in the background.. As stated in the same link above:

> In iOS, the system delivers silent notifications by calling the
>   [application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application):
>   method of your app delegate. Use that method to initiate any download
>   operations needed to fetch new data.

how i usually use it :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any] else {
      //handle something here..
      return 
   }

   //handle the content here...

}
```

You can also perform background tasks from inactive states here by playing with the return value of [completionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibackgroundfetchresult). I suggest you read up on it too.

**For your chat issue...**

Clarify how you're performing this...

*If you're using a websocket/socket.io architecture:*

I would strongly recommend not using notifications to notify a user of anything with APNS when using a websocket. Websockets are very efficient and much quicker. Handling both can greatly complicate things. Stick to the socket approach, and use a method server side that checks if a user is still within the app. Something like a ping-pong method like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914968/how-to-see-ping-pong-in-web-socket-in-ios). Have that method switch to APNS delivery when the socket client ping method shows that the user has left the app or has closed it. This means, if the user is still in the app, but not in the conversation, stay with the ping approach but program the UI response differently (take FB Messenger or Snapchat's notification tabs for example).

*If you are not using websockets/socket.io:*

...Switch to websockets technologies or packages (depending on your server platform type) or [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or use [firebase realtime chat services](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2).

Let me know your setup like i asked earlier, but if youre doing all of this already and still getting the issues, then post your code.

Personnaly, i've used [RawWenderlicht](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) for APNS guides for over a year, good stuff if you ask me.

Comment: I am using php to send notifications with aps, but I want when the app is not runned to hide the badge, alert and sound. Only when the app is runned I want to receive badge,alert and sound.
Capabilities>background modes>notifications>ON

Comment: I think best thing to do here, would be to set up your user's profile in your database with a variable so that: When the user opens the app (in `didLaunchWithOptions`, you make a call to your service to toggle a variable in the user's profile to an 'on' state. When the user closes the app (as in terminates), then on appWillTerminate you make a simple GET call to toggle it back to 'off'. So, when you use aps, you get the user's profile, check the value of that variable, and if it's 'on', you send a normal notification, and if it's off you send a silent notification (`content-available : 0`).

Comment: yes, but when I send content-available : 0 The device doesn't receive the notification at all, not even when the application is turned on.

Comment: Can you update your question with your AppDelegate.swift file?

Comment: Add a copy-paste of the notification you are sending as well, as in what you're pluging into your php script

Comment: Honey comment on the previous post, and pointed out a good thing in his links: The sending of a silent notification requires a special configuration of the notification’s payload. If your payload is not configured properly, the notification might be displayed to the user instead of being delivered to your app in the background. In your payload, make sure the following conditions are true:

The payload’s aps dictionary must include the content-available key with a value of 1.
The payload’s aps dictionary must not contain the alert, sound, or badge keys.

Comment: I think best thing to do, is just dont include the content-available variable when you want to see the notification badge

Answer (score 1):

To `silent` `push notification` the `payload` should contain `content-available` key as:

```
{
  "aps": {
    "content-available": 1
  }
}
```

Also, you need to enable `Remote Notifications` in `Background Modes` under `Capabilities` setting of your `Xcode` project.

[image]

Now your `app will wake up in the background` when it receives one of these `push notifications`.

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` will be called in `AppDelegate` whenever the `push notification` is received.

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
    {
        let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]
        if aps["content-available"] as? Int == 1
        {
            //Your code
        }
    }
```

For more on how to handle push notifications in foreground/background refer to: https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: if it's only thins in aps I don't receive the notification again... I added sound silence.caf and it works but the phone vibrates.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

you can add silent push notifications (set content-available key appropriately) when sending pushes, like below.

```
//when you want the badge and sound
 aps {
   content-available: 1
 }

//When you want silent notifications
 aps {
   content-available: 0
 }
```

This will call the appropriate delegate method but wont display badge and sound

Comment: when I set content-available: 0 without badge and alert I don't receive the notification

Comment: This absolutely incorrect. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). it should be set to `1` when you have something to download which is usually the case with silent notifications